# How can I split a column based on similer values of column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table in which 3 columns `studentid`, `qualification` and `board`. 
It show like

```
Studentid   -   qualification   -      board
   1        -    highschool     -      cbse
   1        -    intermidiate   -      cbse 
   2        -    highschool     -     up board
   2        -    intermidiate   -     up board
```

I need a query that give result like.

```
 studentid  -    qualification-1  -   qualification-2  -   board-1  -   board-2
     1      -     highschool      -    intermidiate    -     cbse    -      cbse
     2      -     highschool      -    intermidiate    -    up board  -    up board
```

Can any one solve it?

Comment: What do you want exactly ? Concat the values of qualification in one column, and concat the ones of board in other ?

Comment: Nope... I don't think you can do that, because studentid is a fieldname and qualification-x are fieldvalues... Use your serverside script to do that

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT studentid, qualification AS 'qualification-1', qualification AS 'qualification-2', board AS 'board-1',  board AS 'board-2'  WHERE 1 GROUP BY studentid`

Use **AS** to create alias of field